# How to return another field and distinct field from mongodb distinct

Tags: mongodb, nosql, distinct

Hello guys I want to ask, how can I return another field in the result of distinct mongodb method?

For example, I have the following documents:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "segment": "AAS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "segment": "AAS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "segment": "BBS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "segment": "CCS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "segment": "DDS",
        "partner": {}
    }
]
```

I want to distinct the segment field, but, I need to return the partner field too:

```
[
    {
        "segment": "AAS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "segment": "BBS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "segment": "CCS",
        "partner": {}
    },
    {
        "segment": "DDS",
        "partner": {}
    }
]
```

How can I produce that? Is it possible to use mapReduce method? how can I implement that?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, you want to distinct by segment, so as the provided example there are 2 AAS, so which document do you want to get?

Comment: Hi @YongShun I've provided the document that I want to return, you can check out my second example

Comment: Yes, you had provided the expected output, but didn't mention clearly the case "AAS", are you trying to get the first document of "AAS" or the last document of "AAS" or any other requirements. Please further elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Aa I see, I just need to get a unique one, so I don't care which "AAS" I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you don't care about which AAS you get. I pick the first one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$segment",
      field: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$field"
  },
  {
    $unset: [ "id", "_id" ]
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IU_QGGZ9QNK)